# mysqldump version mismatch - While exporting from Mysqlworkbench

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I have followed lots of stackoverflow answers to resolve this issue, But couldn't. [Here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644697/mysqlworkbench-giving-version-error-on-exporting-database)

I have also attached a screenshot of the exact error message what I am receiving.[image]

WAMP version : 3.1.7 64bit
Apache: 2.4.37
PHP : 7.2.14
MySQL : 5.7.24
MariaDB : 10.3.12

MySQL Workbench version : 8.0.17

Any help to resolve this issue?

Comment: You're running MariaDB Server, though it's a fork of MySQL there are still differences. Now I don't know the exact differences and if you can ignore the error but the error is there for a good reason, you do not want to lose data while creating a dump of your database.

Comment: Poissbly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644697/mysqlworkbench-giving-version-error-on-exporting-database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqlworkbench giving version error on exporting database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644697/mysqlworkbench-giving-version-error-on-exporting-database)

Comment: Indeed a duplicate question and also the remark about MySQL Workbench being developed and tested for MySQL only. No other database system is supported.