# phpmyadmin is exporting text file instead of sql file

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, export

I'm using PHP version: 7.3.9 with MariaDB 10.4.6 and phpmyadmin through Xampp.

I'm trying to export a large drupal database into an sql file from the export tab on phpmyadmin. But it is exporting as a .txt file.

I am getting an error upon loading the export tab in phpmyadmin that says:

> Warning: a form on this page has more than 1000 fields. On submission,
>   some of the fields might be ignored, due to PHP's max_input_vars
>   configuration.

I have tried increasing the max_input_vars to 5000 (anything above that throws an 'access denied, invalid settings' error).

I have tried to export from MySQL Workbench and it works if you export just the tables but I need one file.

I have tried mysqldump which doesn't seem to work on MariaDB 10.4.6.

I am at a loss as to how to export my database as one sql file. Any suggestions?

Comment: If this is a "php" question as you tagged, can you show us the code you used, or are you doing this via phpmyadmin only? Your question for me, is unclear in that respect.

Comment: If you're doing this in phpmyadmin, you need to select the file type in there. It shows specifically as the `.sql` extension if I do recall, since it's been a while since I've used phpmyadmin directly. If you want the entire database with many tables, then you need to tell it that.

Comment: I have selected the file type as SQL I put PHP as a tag because in my research there have been issues previously with errors like this in PHP 5.

Comment: PHP 5; which exact version? Have a look at this page also https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204403864/export-and-import-mysql-databases

Comment: On mariadb.com [backing up a MariaDB using mysqldump](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/making-backups-with-mysqldump/)

Comment: I figured it out. The mysqldump.exe file was outdated. I fixed it with the help of this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644697/mysqlworkbench-giving-version-error-on-exporting-database#15691080

Comment: @Nick0989 Right on. Would you like me to close as a duplicate using the link you found?

Comment: The phpmyadmin issue wasn't really fixed as it still has the error when trying to export and i'm unsure if the mysqldump.exe file is the cause considering the error. But if you feel you should close as duplicate that's fine with me.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else comes across this error. I figured it out with MySQL Workbench. I would get an error that said mysqldump.exe was version 8 compared to version 10. To fix it I referred to this post: [mysqlworkbench giving version error on exporting database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644697/mysqlworkbench-giving-version-error-on-exporting-database#15691080)

No solution was found for phpmyadmin export though.